# Excel crash when copy worksheet to new workbook

Tags: excel

Select option to move or copy workbook to new workbook. Fatal error.

Select option to move or copy workbook within same workbook, OK.

Only crashes when copy to new. No specific error message, says "Microsoft Excel has stopped working".

Tried clearing conditional formats, cleared a bunch of calculations errors, checked directory permissions - no change. No VBA in file, xlsx format.

Excel 2013, 32bit.

Has anyone else encountered this?

EDIT: 
Recovered an error message code:

Additional information about the problem:
   LCID: 1033
   skulcid: 1033

Comment: Try saving as and then trying to move or copy the workbook into a new workbook. Strange one mate.

Comment: Tried, no change. Tried as xlb as well.

Comment: Next thing that comes to mind is 32-bit problem. Maybe out of memory or something. Try switching calculations to manual under the formulas tab. Sorry, I am a bit stumped but just trying to think of random things. Hard to troubleshoot. Can you get an event log?

Comment: You're thinking along the same lines I was! It probably is memory - but I've had an out-of-memory before (in a previous job) which was caused by the conditional formating and that gave a specific "out of resources" error. Calculations are already on manual (part of the reason I was cleaning up the workbook was how long the calculations were taking). Lots of error flags on page but they are only inconsistent formula warnings.

Comment: System is very locked down - wondering if this would be sufficient to block a specific memory error message. Can't access event log because of how locked down the system is - wyse terminal, no c:, control panel or command prompt. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sheesh. I am out of ideas. Would it not be feasible to just select the entire worksheet (like highlight it), copy it, and past it in a new excel workbook? Or is the memory going to be an issue there as well. If that also crashes I would definitely put my money on a memory issue.